# Onchange listener on radio button that gets added and removed to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have div that can be added and removed to the DOM if the user deleted it or adds it. The first time it gets added, the radio button on change listener fires perfectly but if the div is deleted and re-added the onChange listener no longer works.

HTML

```
<div id="div_container">
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>
   <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"/>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=gender]', function(){
     alert();
});
```

Anybody know how to resolve this?

Comment: Where is the `change` listener? You only posted a `click` listener.

Comment: What you've got should work fine. Can you make an executable snippet or jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Could it be because I'm clearing the div container like this $("#div_container").html("");?

Comment: Im appending the container via Handlebars.js

Comment: No, clearing the container shouldn't be a problem. As long as the element that you bind the handler to is not removed dynamically, the delegation should work. Since you can't remove `document`, your code should work.

Comment: This should work just fine (see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ja44q5cq/)) unless it is something with Handlebars, but i doubt that. Are you sure you arent encounteing JS errors elsewhere?

Comment: After some further exploration, the issue is actually in my handlebars code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that should work. I have created the fiddle with your code and it is working

```
 $(document).on('change', 'input[type=radio][name=gender]', function () {
        alert('hi');
    });
```

Below is the fiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/shrawanlakhe/2ukjLfp0/7/

Answer (score 0):

use `function xxx(){}` and `.find`

Call them in event "added" radio button

```js
var radios = '<input type="radio" name="gender" value="m"/>M<input type="radio" name="gender" value="f"/>F';

function onRchange(){
  
    $(document).find('input[type=radio][name=gender]').on('change', function(){
        alert($(this).val());
     });
  
  }

var i = true;

$('#add-r').on('click',function(){  
  if(i){
    
    $('#div_container').html(radios);
    $(this).html('REMOVE');
    i = false;
  }else{
    $(this).html('ADD');
    $('#div_container').html('');
     i = true;
  }
  
  onRchange();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="div_container">

</div>

<button id="add-r" >ADD</button>
```